# Internet Explorer Iframe recursive window.onblur

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, recursion, onblur

I have a funny problem that I need to solve. In short the Internet Explorer uses the window.onblur event to focus an element in an iFrame. Because of that it's a recursion and you cannot click anything outside of the iFrame. Problem occurs in IE9, IE10, IE11 (not IE8 and below).

Test it here: [Try it (in IE)](http://share.codingyourlife.at/IE_Blur/)

Download it here: [Download it](http://share.codingyourlife.at/IE_Blur/ie_blur.zip)

My real question is:
Is there a way to overwrite the window.onblur event inside the iFrame from outside the iFrame? Is this a Bug and should I report this somewhere to Microsoft?

**Update**

Thanks for your help @Jonathan Sampson, this works as can be seen here:

[See working example](http://share.codingyourlife.at/IE_Blur/working) - you must wait until IFrame is fully loaded to be able to overwrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on the Internet Explorer team and will gladly look into this for you. To answer your question about overwriting the `onblur` handler in the iframe, this *is* possible if the two documents share a common domain. In your example, this is the case.

```js
document.querySelector( "iframe" ).contentWindow.onblur = null;
```

Alternatively, you may only want to bind to the highest window using `window.top`.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. Indeed that works. But you need to wait until the IFrame is loaded or it will be overwritten. I hope there is a good way to do this from outside the IFrame but the question is solved with this answer.

Comment: @CodingYourLife Ideally you should change the code *within* the iframe such that it binds to `window.top` instead, or simply refuses to add a handler to `onblur` if `window !== window.top`. If you need to make the change from the top window, you could bind to the iframe's `DOMContentLoaded` or `Load` event and run your code there, avoiding any need for `setTimeout`.

Comment: Solved my specific problem with a workaround. In my case I had a tabbed navigation that changed the iFrame src (there was no other way). I couldn't hook onto the load event (also no access to iFrame content page) and even tried resetting onblur every 1 second but I could even see in the debugger that onblur did not set to null after the line. What I did was a new onblur event on the page including the iFrame that asks the user if he wants to leave the current tab. If yes I set the IFrame src to about:blank and then overwrite onblur. -> turned it into a "feature" ^^